# Algebraic closure of the field of rational fractions

Tags: field-theory

I was wondering if the field of rational fractions of the variables $x_1,...,x_n$ is algebraically closed?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

No it is not as $X^2-x_1$ has no root.

Comment: ok that was easy... thanks :)

Comment: what does the algebraic closure look like then?